# Testing Spring Scheduler For Job Scheduled Once A Year

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-scheduled

I'm not finding anything online that doesn't involve an example time interval of "run this every 5 seconds" or similar, but upcoming work demands show that we will be running these jobs with much longer time frames. Is there a framework or way to build a test that verifies a job is only called once a year, once a month, etc, or is that just trying to test Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test your code (scheduled job implementation).

The code that stands behind `@Scheduled` annotation is implemented outside your application and therefor you should treat it as a third party (spring in this case). There is no need to test that it works, spring developers already tested it for you.

So, to generalize, you should only test the code of your project.

Now, having said that, there are ways to check the `@Sheduled` code in the integration tests (see [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-scheduled-annotation))

One thing you should be aware of about the scheduling is that it can take some time to simulate this and generally speaking, having test that has to wait for some time just to trigger the code is not a good idea because with tests like this you might end up with the test suite that runs forever :)